# How to inject DbContext in a custom localization provider in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: localization, asp.net-core

As explained in the [asp.net core docs](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/localization.html#using-a-custom-provider) you can configure a custom provider for request localization. As stated in the docs:

> Suppose you want to let your customers store their language and culture in your databases. You could write a provider to look up these values for the user.

For that the following code snippet is provided in the docs and also in the github sample [Localization.StarterWeb](https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/blob/dev/samples/Localization.StarterWeb/Startup.cs):

```
services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options => {
var supportedCultures = new[]
{
    new CultureInfo("en-US"),
    new CultureInfo("fr")
};

options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "en-US", uiCulture: "en-US");
options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;

options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new CustomRequestCultureProvider(async context =>
{
   // My custom request culture logic
   // DbContext needed here <--
  return new ProviderCultureResult("en");
}));});
```

Can anybody explain me how to inject a `DbContext` to load the user specific language from DB in the above function?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, you can't inject it via constructor because you need to instantiate it during `ConfigureServices` method and the container isn't available at this point.

Instead you can resolve via `HttpContext`.

```
public class CustomRequestCultureProvider : RequestCultureProvider
{
    // Note we don't inject any dependencies into it, so we can safely 
    // instantiate in ConfigureServices method
    public CustomRequestCultureProvider() { } 

    public override Task<ProviderCultureResult> DetermineProviderCultureResult(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        var dbContext = httpContext.RequestServices
            .GetService<AppDbContext>();
    }
}
```

Be aware though that this may be less than optimal, as you'll have calls to database on every request, so maybe it's worth to abstract this further and use an caching strategy depending on what exactly you want to do with the `DbContext`.

Usually one should avoid database calls in culture providers, filters etc. for performance reasons

**Update:**

There is a generic version of `GetService<T>`, but you need to import the namespace via `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;`.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! Your provided code sample has two small mistakes: the `class` keyword in front of the constructor and the method `GetService` is not generic so you have to call `GetService(typeof(AppDbContext));`

Comment: Updated the question with both the fix and how to use the `GetService<T>`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the usage of `GetService<T>`